# How to choose the input parameters for a Beta-Pert distribution if no expert estimates can be elicited?

Tags: beta-distribution, uncertainty, risk

The Beta-Pert-Distribution is often used to model uncertainty in risk management. It takes three values a minimum, maximum and most likely (mode).

Generally, these numbers ought to be provided by expert judgement or historical data.

My question: I am using the Beta-Pert distribution in the context of academic research. I model a relatively new phenomena, where there is little data. I have found data on most likely input values. Yet, I am wondering how I could come up with upper (maximum) and lower (minimum) thresholds.

Is there a generally acceptable heuristic I could apply? (e.g. max value 200% of mode to account for tail estimates?)